# Multiplying custom trainable parameter to hidden units

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

I want to take square of the difference between the tensors/output after the LSTM layer and multiply it with the trainable parameter.

As pointed out by @rvinas, I tried to write my own layer for the purpose,

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,W_regularizer=None,W_constraint=None, **kwargs):
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.W = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint,
                                trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)
```

The call function is multiplying only the tensors and Weight which I have initialized. Still I need to find how to take the pairwise difference and square them.

```
    def call(self, x):
        uit = K.dot(x, self.W)
        return uit

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[-1]
```

But then I am getting `AssertionError`at `assert len(input_shape) >= 3`.

I want to perform:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, LSTM
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

lstm=LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(input)
something=MyLayer()(lstm)
```

Comment: The Lambda layer is stateless. That is, for any custom operation with trainable parameters, you implement define your own layer (see [this](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/)).

Comment: Also, the operation `add` should be wrapped in a Lambda layer.

Comment: And isn't `subtracted` going to be zeros all the time?

Comment: @rvinas Thanks and Yes, the `subtracted` is going to zero all the time. I am stupid. I want to do `[h2-h1,h3-h2.......]`.

Comment: @rvinas I tried creating my own layer. But still I am puzzled about how to perform `[h2-h1,h3-h2...]` Also, the input shape for `MyLayer`will then be not same as lstm output. The size will be `n-1` where `n` is the number of outputs from lstm. So, I am little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe this is what you intend to do:

```
def call(self, x):
    diff = K.square(x[:, 1:, :] - x[:, :-1, :])  # Shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps-1, hidden_dim)
    uit = K.dot(diff, self.W[:, None])  # Shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps-1, 1)
    uit = K.squeeze(uit, axis=-1)  # Shape=(batch_size, nb_timesteps-1)
    return uit
```

**NOTE**: Not tested.

Comment: Thank you @rvinas I need the output from call to be 3D tensor as I will ned to feed it into other layer (other LSTM). So, I didn't do `K.squeeze(uit, axis=-1).` The dimension of `uit` are `(?,?,1).` Now since the output needs to be fed to LSTM, I changed in `compute_output_shape` I returned `1,input_shape[-1]`. `1` because of the dimension of `uit`. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In this case the output shape would be `(input_shape[0], input_shape[1]-1, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you. I have had Embedding layer of Dimension `None,100,300` so I am not sure if the output_shape will be `(input_shape[0], input_shape[1]-1, 1)` because that gives me `None,99,1` which in my opinion should be `None,127,1` in this case as there are 128 LSTM units. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Then I might have misunderstood your idea. If you want an output shape of `(input_shape[0], input_shape[2]-1,1)`, shouldn't the shape of `self.W` be `(input_shape[1],)`, in order to compute the dot product?

Comment: I want to take the difference between the encoding of the words in the sentence.

Comment: I understand this, but I don't get why the shape of `self.W` is `(input_shape[2],)` if you want to take the dot product with a tensor `diff` of shape `(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2]-1)` and get a tensor of shape `(input_shape[0], input_shape[2]-1,1)` as output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have accepted our answer! Thanks a lot